React Draggable: Click and release to drag?
When using React Draggable, normally you click and hold down the button to select and drag an item with the mouse. Is there a way to just click an item and release the mouse button, and that item attaches the the cursor and you are able to drag it around that way? I am using react-xarrows and trying to select an endpoint to drag by click-and-release.
Thanks, Mike
Tried preventing the mouseup event, stopimmediatepropagation on mouseup event, but that isn't working.
clickCoa.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
      console.log('mouseup');
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopImmediatePropagation()
      return false;
    });

